How do generate strapi faker data for blocks
In my strapi backend src/index.ts i have this code
async bootstrap({ strapi }: { strapi: Core.Strapi }) {
    await strapi.db.query('api::article.article').deleteMany({});
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      const title = faker.lorem.words({ min: 3, max: 10 });
      const slug = slugify(title, { lower: true });

      await strapi.service("api::article.article").create({
        data: {
          title,
          slug, // Generate and assign slug here
          date: faker.date.anytime()
        }
      });
    }

this works well, but I dont understand how I can create blocks
tried to do this :

blocks: [
            {
              __typename: "ComponentSharedRichText",
              id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
              body: faker.lorem.paragraphs()
            }
          ]

but I get an ambigious error when I run it

Finally figured out the answer
blocks: [
            {
              __component: 'shared.rich-text', // Example component
              body: faker.lorem.paragraphs({ min: 5, max: 15 }),
            },
          ],

You can find the component name in src/api/article/content-types/article/schema.json
